# TwitterKit does not compile with Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, twitter, fabric.io

I added TwitterKit from Fabric to an app under Xcode 6.3.

The app would compile before I added TwitterKit's Run Script build phase step but once I added TwitterKit it failed with this error during Debug builds:

> 2015-02-23 11:22:32.382 run[53735:1513077] Fabric.framework/run 1.3.13
>   2015-02-23 11:22:32.388 run[53735:1513077]
>
> Fabric: dSYM Error
>
> Unable to process fabrictest.app.dSYM at path /Users/mfoouser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fabrictest/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/fabrictest.app.dSYM
>   Make sure your project build settings are generating a dSYM file. DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT should be set to dwarf-with-dsym for all configurations. This could also be a timing issue, make sure the Fabric run script build phase is the last build phase and no other scripts have moved the dSYM from the location Xcode generated it.
>
> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Anyone find a way around this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This was a simple fix. Just do as the error state, turn on dSYM generation for your debug build.

Change your Build Settings from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

Then choose Build again. It should now compile and run.

Comment: Hi Mark, unfortunately this still does not work for me. Any other way to make sure the dSYM is created?

Comment: I got the same problem when I'm changing to ARC project that has Fabric inside.

Comment: Images have broken links.

Comment: 1 vp vote for the graphical illustration of the build settings.

Answer (score 13):

You can follow below steps  ,it worked for me.

1. open build setting of your project and search for **"Generate debug symbol"** and set it to Yes.
   As in the below screenshot
   [image]
2. Search for debug information format in build setting and search for  **"Debug information format"** then set "Debug information format" to **"DWARF with dSYM file"**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. But can you explain the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 4):

This didn't work for me since it was already set to 'with dSYM' and it didn't build as well. After more digging and trying things out, it seems like the issue (for me at least) is under Build Settings > Generate Debug Symbols, which was set to No by default. I changed it to Yes and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

No one of proposed answers worked out for me.

Deleted both `Fabric.framework` and `Crashlytics.framework` which were added via Fabric app and added them again through `Cocoapods`.

**It doesnt mean that `Cocoapods` is only workaround, but probably that they should be re-added to project again.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the previous answers combined:

1- Change "Build Settings -> Debug Information Format -> Debug" value to "DWARF with dSYM File"

2- Change "Build Settings -> Generate Debug Symbols" value to "Yes"

3- Remove Fabric and Crashlytics frameworks and install again